# Homomorphism between vector spaces in MAGMA

Tags: computational-algebra, magma-cas

I've recently started to use Magma, and I'm stuck with the following problem.

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$, $p$ prime and let $t$ be the generator of the extension. Let $R := \mathbb{F}_q[X,Y]$ and $f \in R$, then I can write $f = g(X,Y) + h(X,Y)t$ where $g,h \in A := \mathbb{F}_p[X,Y]$, so I have an isomorphism between $A^2$ and $R$ as $\mathbb{F}_p-$vector spaces.
I would like to write this isomorphism in Magma, but I'm not even able to write $A^2$ as a $\mathbb{F}_p-$vector space.

Thank you in advance!

**Edit**: what I really need is from the polynomial $f \in R$, have the two polynomials $g,h \in A$. Any other advice that does not involve homomorphisms is welcome!

Comment: When you work with these structures, they are (in the view of Magma), multivariate polynomial rings, not vector spaces (of course mathematically they are viewed as vector spaces). If you want a vector space homomorphism, you should work with vector spaces `VectorSpace(F_q,2)` and `VectorSpace(F_p,4)`.

Comment: There are also built-in methods to change the base ring, you should look into these in the documentation; in either the chapter on Vector Spaces, or on Multivariate Polynomial Rings, depending on what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that. Do you have any suggestions on how to obtain the two polynomials $g$ and $h$?

Comment: `ElementToSequence` can be applied to the coefficients to write $\mathbb{F}_{q} \ni a = c + bt$ as a vector $(b,c) \in \mathbb{F}_{p}^{2}$ (or I guess technically as a sequence of length 2).

Comment: So I will probably define a new function that uses ElementToSequence for that...I can't find anything "ready to use" on the manual. It seems easier then using vector spaces. Thank you for your help!